# Is it possible to express acceleration in a gravitational field as a logarithmic spiral?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, spacetime, acceleration

The derivation starts from a logarithmic spiral:

$r=de^{b\theta}$

The lenght of a part of the spiral i calculated by:

$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \sqrt{(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2+r^2} d\theta$

From 0 to 2$\pi $:

$l=d\sqrt{b^2+1}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{b\theta} d\theta=\frac{d\sqrt{b^2+1}}{b}(e^{b2\pi}-1)$

The difference in radius:

$s=r_{2\pi}-r_0=d(e^{b2\pi}-1)$

The acceleration can now be calculated by the distance *s* the an object has moved by the time *t*.

$a=\frac{2s}{t}$

The time is the time it takes for an object to move the distance *l* at the speed of light:

$t=\frac{l}{v}=\frac{\frac{d\sqrt{b^2+1}}{b}(e^{b2\pi}-1)}{c}$

$a=\frac{2c^2b^2}{d(e^{b2\pi b}-1)(b^2+1)}$

Compare to gravity on earth and other planets the constants are found:

$d=r,    b=k\frac{m}{r}$

Final expression:

$a=\frac{2c^2k^2m^2} {r^3(e^{2\pi \frac{km}{r}}-1)(\frac{k^2m^2}{r^2} +1)}$

where $k=\frac{\pi G}{c^2}$

Expressed in terms of the Schwarzschild radius:

$a=\frac{\pi^2 c^2r^2_s} {2r^3(e^{\pi^2 \frac{r_s}{r}}-1)(\frac{\pi^2 r^2_s}{4r^2} +1)}$

It predicts the acceleration *a* of particles towards a large object with mass *m* at large distances *r* compared to $r_s$ accurate, but differs from Newton and Einstein at small distances.

Is there any physical reality behind this equation or does it just give a very good approximation on larger scales?

Comment: We could only answer this question if we had more information about your starting points. For example does "moving through spacetime at the speed of light" just mean that the 4-velocity has magnitude $c$ as is trivial, or are you actually talking about a null ray? Is the "logarithmic spiral in spacetime" a logarithmic spiral in space stretched into a helix by a time coordinate, or is it doing something unphysical like going backwards in time?

Comment: Given a couple assumptions about what you're talking about, for example, one could say "well yes, there is some physical reality behind this equation as any elliptical or circular orbit must necessarily be approximable by the sorts of logarithmic spirals you're describing, so it's no surprise that there's a regime where the spiral orbit starts to look like a circular orbit and you recover the formula for long-distance Newtonian gravity."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a two body system and gravitational interaction, we can completely solve the problem. This gives us the allowed orbits namely: circular, elliptic, parabolic and hyperbolic orbits depending on the energy of the particles.  If you are in the newtonian limit, you have to state all the forces acting on your particle and given initial conditions ;this uniquely chooses a path in phase space. In GR, you have to first (in the simplest cases) state your metric and then solve Einstein's field equations.What you have done is started with an equation of motion and massaged it by plugging into it different constants. This is not how physics is done. Any correct prediction it makes will be completely coincidental since there is no reason from the physical point of view why the equation of motion was a logarithmic spiral to begin with.